# Is there anything like a "WAIT" function in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I would like to create a Fortran program that staggers text to create a sort of rhythm. Is there any way to do this within the Fortran 90 standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not within the standard. But it is not the sort of thing that is typically in the language standards, rather in the system-specific libraries.

The closest to the standard is the community-driven [Fortran Standard Library](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib) which contains the [`stdlib_system`](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib/blob/master/src/stdlib_system.F90) module with the `sleep()` subroutine that calls the system-specific libraries for you. The integer argument is the number of milliseconds to wait.

Many compilers offer a `sleep()` intrinsic subroutine or function that will pause the execution for a certain number of seconds or miliseconds or some other time interval. See the manual to your compiler. E.g., https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SLEEP.html

There are also various system functions callable through the interoperability with C (Fortran 2003), such as the POSIX [`sleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), [`usleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) or [`nanosleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html). Examples of calling them from Fortran are available on the web, e.g., [here](https://scivision.github.io/fortran2018-examples/sourcefile/sleep_std.f90.html) or  [here](https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/sleep.html).

Similar system commands are also callable in various operating systems through the command line (`execute_command_line` in Fortran). E.g., [sleep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) and
[usleep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usleep) in Linux.

---

Be also aware that the Fortran 90 standard is extremely old and that many of the intrinsic procedures available in standard Fortran came later.